# Javascript determine NULL type is string or not in JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert JSON object to a string. However, for NULL value in the string, I must change it to an empty string. For it, I overwrite the replacer function

```
var str = JSON.stringify(rec, function (k, v) { return (v !== null) ? v : ''; });
```

It works fine. However, it will also change all non-string type value to an empty string. For example, I have the following object

```
Order Record
------------
   OrderId [int] NOT NULL,
   ProductId [int] NOT NULL
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ReferralMemberId [int] NULL,
   Notes [nvarchar](64) NULL
```

If I use the function above, when **ReferralMemberId** is NULL, the field will become empty string. Ideally, I would like **ReferralMemberId** to keep to be NULL, but **Notes** to become empty string.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: How would you know if a JSON key was supposed to have a string value?

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes that is my question too... I guess there is no way around it. I've accepted the answer below until there is a better answer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON, values must be one of the following data types:

- a string
- a number
- an object (JSON object)
- an array
- a boolean
- null

So, **typeof value == 'string'** doesn't work here, as **null** is also a data type.

We can solve this by using an extra hashmap.

1. Declare a HashMap.
2. Store your data Fields name as key and their data type as value.
3. Then check during JSON conversion as the data type is a string or not.

```
let map = new Map();
map.set('OrderId','int');
map.set('ProductId','int');
map.set('ReferralMemberId','int');
map.set('Notes','string');
...
...
function (key, value) { 
    if (map.get(key) === 'string'){
       if(value !== null){
         return value;
       }else{
         return '';
       }
    }else{
       return value;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Kawser, the problem is that I wouldn't know what object is returned by the webserver. I guess, there is no way around it. I'll accept your answer until there is a better answer available.

Comment: This is quite difficult then. We can continuously monitor and update the map. But this will be very costly when we want to update the string based on the modified map.